# Ontario College Advanced Diploma (OCAD) what is equivalent in US?

Tags: united-states, canada

I have 3 year Advanced Diploma form Ontario want to ask what is equivalent in US ?

Comment: Sounds like an Associate degree. One step below Bachelor's, right?

Comment: Probably more appropriate for [Academics.se]

Comment: For reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontario_College_Advanced_Diploma

Answer (score 1):

First, it is important to recognize that there is often no such thing as "equivalent" between different nations.  That said, this sounds like it might be considered as somewhere between an Associates Degree and a Bachelor's Degree in the US system.

My recommendation is that you should expect people in the US to not know what the degree is, and to include a sentence or two in your CV / resume that explains its nature and what it means about your education.